# Jquery dialog buttons return value

Tags: jquery

I am using a jquery dialog, and what i want to implement is when user press "ok“， the progamming keep going, when press "cancel", it stoped.

```
    function displaymessage()
{
 $("#confirm").dialog({      
    buttons:{
                "OK":function(){$(this).dialog("close"); test(1);},
                "Cancel":function(){$(this).dialog("close");test(0);}        
            }
        });  
function test(bool)
{
if(bool==1)
return true;
else return false;
}
return test();
}



<div id="confirm"></div>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="return displaymessage()" />
```

But how to control the function test run after user click "ok" button?

thanks

​​​​​

Comment: why do you have an extra `return test` in the test function???

Comment: @rutwikreddy give the test() value to displaymeesage(), so in the onclick event, if it is false, the button will stop submit. that is what i am thinking, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take  2 buttons

```
<asp:button id="submit" onclientclick="return displaymessage()" />

<asp:button id="submit_hidden" onclick="submit_OnClick" runat="server"/>
```

Hide the button with id `submit_hidden`. (may be via css dsiplay:none;)

And in jquery change the code

```
$("#confirm").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,        
    buttons:{
                "OK":function(){ $("#submit_hidden").click();
                                 $(this).dialog("close"); },
                "Cancel":function(){ $(this).dialog("close");}        
            }
        });
```

Now you don't need to return anything.

Comment: Thank you very much, this two buttons idea do solve my problem and i modified the code from click() to trigger(). thanks

Comment: May I know the reason of negative voting?

Answer (score 1):

```
function displaymessage()
{
 $("#confirm").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,        
    buttons:{
                "OK":function(){  test(1); $(this).dialog("close"); },
                "Cancel":function(){ test(0); $(this).dialog("close");}        
            }
        });  
}


function test(bool)
{
  if(bool==1)
      return  true;
  else 
      return false;
}
```

Comment: which function should be called in the button onclick? how can i stop button submit when user click cancel?

Comment: I'm not getting you. What gets submitted?

Comment: it's actually an <asp:button id="submit" onclick="submit_OnClick" onclientclick="return displaymessage()" runat="server"/> if the displaymessage() return false, it won't run "submit_OnClick" which is the code on the server side. So how can I give the bool value to "displaymessage()" function?

Comment: I'm adding another answer as it would not be readable here in comment