# jquery button trigger server side onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using a jquery dialog, when user click ok, the server side onclick event should be fired, if click cancel, nothing happened.

i have to prevent the click function at the beginning by preventDefault() function.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#<%=submit.ClientID %>").click(function (event) {
             event.preventDefault();
                $("#confirm").dialog({
                    buttons: {
                        "OK": function () {  $(this).dialog("close"); 
                              Here should be the code to trigger the server side click event


                     },
                        "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close");},
                    } 
                });
         });
     });
```

I don't know how to trigger a server side onclick event. any ideas? thanks

Comment: The only way to do anything on the server-side from javascript is to either send an ajax request, or submit a form either through the current page or an iframe. How can you have a click event on the server-side? the GUI doesn't exist on the server-side.

Comment: @KevinB I am newbie of jquery. as I know, the asp.net button has onclick event and onclientclick event, onclick event is on the server side, i want to fire that event when user click "ok"

Comment: Did one of the answers help you?  If so, please mark the answer or provide feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10583339/1202242

I used two button, and one is hidden. 
It solved my problem perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Put the `event.preventDefault()` in the cancel part or some kind of condition for it so it isn't running on every click.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are confusing between server and client sides.
if you want to trigger event on the server side you need to notify him (can be done by ajax call). the click event is a client side event that will not do anything on the server side.
try to put some code under the "OK" function to notify the server whatever you want like via [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call.

anyway you should move the `event.preventDefault()` call into the "Cancel" function.

edit: another way to approach it is to prevent the submit to happen if you don't want it. at your form tag add `onsubmit="foo()"`
and define:

```
function foo(){
   //call your dialog and return true to continue the submit and false to cancel.
}
```

Comment: if I move the event.preventDefault() into the "cancel" function, the server side code will run when click the "submit" button before user click the "ok" on the popuped dialog

Comment: so if you don't want to create a submit you need to put it at the beginning (like you did) and call $("#your_form_id").submit() manually on "OK" function or create an ajax call instead.

Comment: that is my problem, I tried to use $("#your_form_id").submit() which didn't fire submit_onClick() function on the server side, and i don't know how to use an ajax, could you give me some example?

Comment: i updated my comment. your dialog function should return a value. pass this value to the function called on submit event.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a little bit dependant on implementation details (even if they're so widely used that they won't be changed) but code is this:

```
__doPostBack('submit','OnClick');
```

This will execute the `OnClick` event handler for the control named `submit`. As reference take a look to this little tutorial about [how postbacks works in ASP.NET](http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=18).

Comment: @Pita I remember some issues (with some some browsers) related to buttons with ID "submit". I'm not sure so any information will be welcome. Anyway this should be work (I use it too) but you _may_ have to rename your button to something else.