# Trying to make confirmation box with JavaScript, JQuery…not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new-ish to JQuery and JS, so this is probably something basic that I'm just missing. In my HTML I have a form:

```
<form  action="" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm_del()">
     //….etc…..
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

I want to make a confirmation box for the delete button. So I have the following, which is to be the text of the confirmation box:

```
<div id='confirmation_dialogue'>
Pressing 'Delete' will delete this item from the database. This action cannot be undone <br><br>
Pressing Cancel will not change the database.
</div>
```

Under that, I have the following in order to handle the onSubmit function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function confirm_del(){
    alert("cd");
    $("#confirmation_dialogue").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
        title : "<div class='widget-header'><h4><i class='icon-ok'></i> Delete Item </h4>      </div>",
        buttons : [{
            html : "Cancel",
            "class" : "btn btn-default",
            click : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
        }, {
            html : "Delete",
            "class" : "dialog btn btn-info",
            click : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return true;
            }
        }]

    });
}
//…..and so on, until the </script>
```

What happens is that the text of the confirmation box appears at the bottom of the screen--as if there is no JQ function addressing it. But If I take the JQ out of the confirm_del() function, I can't seem to get confirm_del to successfully call it. Even now, with it in the function, it seems to be ignored--the confirm box does not appear, and the delete happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/swncapgj/)

I would not recommend using **inline JS**; it's just bad practice. Plus, for a reason that someone else may explain better, the `return true` and `return false` from the `dialog` button click handlers would not work the way you expect them to ... there's a break in execution that would not allow these to `true/false` to be return values of the function. Separate your markup and JS cleanly as follows:

HTML

```
<form id="del_form"  action="" method="post"> <!-- <<<<<<<== -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>

<div id='confirmation_dialogue'>
Pressing 'Delete' will delete this item from the database. This action cannot be undone <br><br>
Pressing Cancel will not change the database.
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#confirmation_dialogue").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
        title : "<div class='widget-header'><h4><i class='icon-ok'></i> Delete Item </h4>      </div>",
        buttons : [{
            html : "Cancel",
            "class" : "btn btn-default",
            click : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }, {
            html : "Delete",
            "class" : "dialog btn btn-info",
            click : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $('#del_form')[0].submit(); //<<<<<<<===
            }
        }]

    });

    $('#del_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#confirmation_dialogue').dialog('open'); //<<<<<<===
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an e argument to the confirm_del() function and in the first line place an e.preventDefault(). Like this:

```
function confirm_del(e) {
e.preventDefault();
alert("cd");
$("#confirmation_dialogue").dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    modal : true,
    title : "<div class='widget-header'><h4><i class='icon-ok'></i> Delete Item </h4>      </div>",
    buttons : [{
        html : "Cancel",
        "class" : "btn btn-default",
        click : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            return false;
        }
    }, {
        html : "Delete",
        "class" : "dialog btn btn-info",
        click : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            return true;
        }
    }]

});
}
```

You also need to have a hidden submit which is called from the click function since the return true/false there returns to the click function and not to the parent function. See this post on how to implement that: [Jquery dialog buttons return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552440/jquery-dialog-buttons-return-value)

Comment: What if I initiated a function and set it to equal the JQ function (ex: $bool = $("#confirmation_dialogue").dialog…..), and then returned $bool?

Comment: The functions in click don't return to the parent function but to the click. Basically it does nothing except handle the click.